# Output Impedance of a Wilson Current Mirror

Tags: transistors, analog, bjt, current-mirror, ideal

Is the ideal output impedance of a Wilson Current Mirror 0?

Also, in the formula for the actual output impedance of Wilson Current Formula (i.e. R_out = [B/2]* r_o), what does r_o stand for? Also, what is the order of magnitude of a Wilson Current Mirror?

Comment: \$r_o\$ represents the small-signal output resistance defined by the early voltage and the collector current.

Comment: Think about it - ideally, it would have infinite output impedance, so no matter what load you attached to, the total impedance (and therefore current) would still be the same. Infinite + Load ≈ Infinite, so your current remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The mirror like an ideal current source has infinite impedance except for the leakage r_o due to the Early Effect and Beta, B

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/How_the_Wilson_current_mirror_equalizes_the_currents

Order of magnitude for current depends on the device Imax, Pmax and gain matching

Comment: I recall building a Wilson current mirror out of discretes, with emitter swamping resistors. The Rout was 5 Million ohms, running at 10mA, measured on a Fairchild curve tracer.